# Euler characteristic of branch cover of punctured Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

Let $\Sigma_1$,  $\Sigma_2$ be two closed Riemann surfaces, $\pi: \Sigma_1 \to \Sigma_2$ is degree $m$ branched cover of $\Sigma_2$, then we have formula about their Euler number:
$$\chi(\Sigma_1)= m\chi(\Sigma_2) - \Sigma_{p \in \Sigma_1}(e_p-1),$$
where $e_p$ is e ramification index at $p$.

> Now suppose  $\pi: \Sigma_1 \to \Sigma_2$ is still a  degree $m$ branched cover of $\Sigma_2$, but $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$ are punctured Riemann surfaces. If there is a version of Riemann–Hurwitz formula for this case?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I guess that  the same formula holds for the punctured case. For example,    suppose that  both  $\Sigma_1$,  $\Sigma_2$ have only one puncture $p$, $q$ and $\pi$ is degree $m$.  $\Sigma_1'=  \Sigma_1\cup p$,   $\Sigma_2'=  \Sigma_2\cup q$ are two closed surfaces,  $\pi: \Sigma_1' \to \Sigma_2' $ is still a degree $m$ branched cover, but the puncture $p$  will become a new branch point. By usual  Riemann–Hurwitz formula, $\chi(\Sigma_1') = m\chi(\Sigma_2') -b_0 - b_p$, where b_0 counting the branch points away from $p$, and $b_p=m-1$ is ramification index at $p$.

Comment: Hence, $\chi(\Sigma_1)= m\chi(\Sigma_2) - b_0$. But I am not sure.